# Having two versions of CUDA GPU Toolkit SDK installed, how to remove one?

Tags: uninstall, cuda

I currently two versions of the Toolkit installed `cuda-9.2` and `cuda-8.0`, how can I safely remove the `8.0`?

I saw a question where the most voted answer was removing the whole folder, which doesn't seem safe to me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall cuda-8-0:

1. Uninstall CUDA
2. Clean your local repo
3. Clean up not needed CUDA dependencies

Do the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run cuda-8-0
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you have cuDNN packages installed use:

```
dpkg -l | grep libcudnn*
```

To remove unwanted packages use:

```
dpkg --purge <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install "Synaptic Package Manager" -> open synaptic manager and type in root password-> in the bottom left go to Status-> If you have installed using web browser or dpkg command then it would have a section in top left "Installed (local or obsolete)" safely remove CUDA from there, If you installed using apt-get from default repos it would be in section (Installed Manually) now safely remove it.

To remove unwanted dependencies dont worry it wont delete anything which would be needed by any other package ,"sudo apt-get autoremove".